# Remove qTip when the path is changed manually

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, qtip2

I have created a login page with username and password showing qtip to enter credentials on document ready and have a home button which redirects to */Home* from  */Login* which doesn't require to Login

home button function is

```
     $scope.GoToHome = function()
    {
      //to remove qTip when redirected
        $('#username').qtip("destroy");
        $('#password').qtip("destroy");
        $location.path("/Home");
    }
```

I have to remove qtip when ever the user changes the path to any except */Login* , with out calling a function ,what if the user directly change from address bar.

Now my question is  How could i remove qtip when user changes path directly in address bar.? is there any event that auto check the url and show the qtip onLoad ?